# Separate plot titles within lapply

Tags: r, ggplot2, lapply

I have a number of objects which I would like to plot together on one page, with a separate title for each. At the moment, I have a vector of plot titles which I feed into ggtitle within lapply, but it adds only the first entry of this vector to each plot.

A quick and ugly minimal example is below:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

#My 'data'
A.a <- rnorm(10)
A.b <- rnorm(30)
lmnames <- ls(pattern = "A.*")

titlenames <- c("Plot A", "Plot B")

plotlist <- list()
#I have a more complex ggplot function in reality, but I'm using qplot here as a placeholder.
plotlist <- lapply(lmnames, FUN=function(x,y){qplot(get(x)) + ggtitle(y)}, y=titlenames)

grid.arrange(grobs = plotlist)
```

It looks like this:
[image: Incorrect titles using ggtitle in lapply]

You can see, both plots are labelled "Plot A". I'd like to have each plot labelled accordingly. Can anyone help me see what I'm missing here? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is, that in all your plots, your title is "Plot A" "Plot B", see `plotlist[[1]]$labels$title`.

A working code is the following:

```
plotlist <- lapply(1:length(lmnames), function(x){
  qplot(get(lmnames[x])) + ggtitle(titlenames[x])
})
```

I'm sure there are more elegant solutions. But this one will work.

Regards,
J_F

Answer (score 2):

Looping over multiple variables is often cleaner with mapply,

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

dl <- list("Plot A" = rnorm(10), "Plot B" = rnorm(10))
plot_fun <- function(x, y) qplot(x) + ggtitle(y)
grid.arrange(grobs = Map(plot_fun, x = dl, y = names(dl)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is nice, but is there a way to grab all similar named objects from the workspace, the way I use `lmnames <- ls(pattern = "A.*")`, and name them automatically, rather than doing the naming and object listing manually like in your example? I ask because in my real scenario, I have more than just 2 objects that I want to plot.

Comment: `mget` could help, but it's usually a good idea not to have many objects lying around in the workspace. Keeping them together in a list throughout is usually a better strategy in R.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine:

```
plotlist <- lapply(1:2, FUN=function(i){qplot(get(lmnames[i])) + ggtitle(titlenames[i])})
```

Or this:

```
plotlist <- apply(data.frame(lmnames, titlenames), 1, FUN=function(x){qplot(get(x[1])) + ggtitle(x[2])})
```

[image]

The issue is that in both iteration, only the first value of `y=titlenames` is read in